# Android OpenStreetMap Coordinates

Tags: java, android, url, https

I have a class which fetches the coordinates from OpenStreetMap. It works perfectly when I execute it from a normal Java class: I wrote a test class in android studio and just execute it's main method.

Here's my test clas which works and prints correct results:

```
public class openstreetmaptest {
    static String address2 = "Platz der Republik 1, 11011 Berlin";
    static String address1 = "Willy-Brandt-Straße 1, 10557 Berlin";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Location testL = new Location(address1);
        Location test2 = new Location(address2);
        System.out.println("distance: " + testL.distanceBetween(test2));
        System.out.println("lat 1: " + testL.getLat());
        System.out.println("lng 1: " + testL.getLng());
        System.out.println("lat 2: " + test2.getLat());
        System.out.println("lng 2: " + test2.getLng());
    }
}
```

Important part of Location class:

```
public double distanceBetween(Location x)   {
    double earthRadius = 6371000; //meters
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(x.getLat()-getLat());
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(x.getLng()-getLng());
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(Math.toRadians(getLat())) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(x.getLat())) *
                    Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    double dist = earthRadius * c;
    return dist;
}


private void calculateDegrees()  {
    Map<String, Double> coords;
    coords = OpenStreetMapUtils.getInstance().getCoordinates(address);
    lat = coords.get("lat");
    lng = coords.get("lon");
}
```

In my Android project I have a class which extends AppCompatActivity. 
After a button is pressed by the user I'm getting his input Strings from the UI fields (address information). With those I'm creating a Location object. Here the coords calculation doesn't work anymore.

It seems to crash here:

```
 private String getRequest(String url) throws Exception {

    final URL obj = new URL(url);
    final HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    if (con.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        return null;
    }

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    return response.toString();
}
```

Check out the reference to see the full code of the request to OpenStreetMap.

`android.permission.INTERNET` & `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` are included in my manifest.

This is my reference for getting the coordinates: [link](http://julien.gunnm.org/geek/programming/2015/09/13/how-to-get-geocoding-information-in-java-without-google-maps-api/)

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Dont link to a 3rd party site for "reference". **Include** the essential parts of the code in your question. We have otherwise no idea what you did exactly. We cant help with code that we cant see.